# RubyMineで行全体を一括でインデントする方法

Tags: rubymine

RubyMineを使って開いているファイル全体を再インデントしたいのですが、
`Select All`, `Auto Indent lines` の二つのコマンドが必要になります。

これら2つの連続するコマンドを一つのショートカットに設定するか、
もしくは期待する動作を一度に行えるコマンドはRubyMineにありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformat機能で出来ます。

参考サイト
http://blog.mah-lab.com/2014/12/03/rubymine-reformat/

Comment: 求めてた機能以上に便利でした、ありがとうございます！